# bad_certificate when executing an API in WSO2Carbon

Tags: ssl-certificate, wso2

Although my site's certificate is fine, ("openssl verify mysite.com.cer" resulted in OK), and my site is ssl-certified including green lock in the url-bar, my site is generating a fatal alert: bad_certificate whenever a subscriber in my WSO2 app executes an api.

```
[2018-06-08 10:54:47,167] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.decryptData(SSLIOSession.java:378)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:413)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:218)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I browsed through several stackoverflow-questions about 'bad_certificate' but found no solution.

To import my certificate I followed [WSO2's docs](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/setting-up-wso2-with-a-valid-certificate):

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in SSL_certificate_www_mysite_com.crt -inkey www.mysite.com.key -name "mykeys" -certfile mysite.com.cer -out mykeys.pfx
 keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykeys.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore mykeys.jks -deststoretype JKS
 keytool -export -alias "mykeys" -keystore mykeys.jks -file mykeys.pem
 copied mykeys.pem and mykeys.jks to /usr/local/opt/wso2am-2.2.0/repository/resources/security/
 keytool -import -alias "mykeys" -file mykeys.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon and answered yes to include the certificate
```

Then I had to change several configuration files to use mykeys instead of wso2carbon. So I did.

Then I restarted wso2-carbon, logged in and checked that mykeys.JKS showed up in the list of keystores, it does.

My site is correctly ssl-certified, green lock showing in the url-bar. All works fine, upto the point that logged in as Subscriber I try to Execute an API, which results in the response "ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate" and the above-mentioned log coming from [sourcehandler](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/passthru/SourceHandler.java)

This error is logged in repository/logs/wso2-apigw-errors.log and wso2carbon.log, but only this message, nothing else.

Where to look next to find why my certificate is not getting validated correctly?

Comment: Could you please enable SSL debug logs and see what is happening? https://burnthecode.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/ssl-debugging-with-wso2-products/

Comment: Nice one, For ssl only: wso2server.sh -Djavax.net.debug=ssl. Thanks. Got some logbrowsing to do now.

Comment: Interesting. I tried the above command too and it spits out a lot of info about the certs but it doesn't specify which the bad cert is. Is there a way to identify which the cert is as far as WSO2 APIM goes?

Answer (score 3):

the problem is in the self-signed certificate

assume your service published at this endpoint:

```
https://192.168.99.3:8243/first/1.0.0
```

then you have to go into a new browser window

```
https://192.168.99.3:8243/
```

set browser to always accept the https certificate

after this the call in api console should work

Comment: I added a comment above. While this may help, it looks like the above problem occurred when there was an API call. In our case the logs are constantly being spewed out.
How do we identify which the bad cert is?

Comment: need to see a stacktrace to understand when it happened

Comment: The stack trace is identical to that posted by OP. There really isn't anything else. It occurs every 10 sec. I am looking at the load balancer healthcheck but again, the logs don't help narrow down much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate Store and gateway instances, open the gateway:9443/carbon in browser and accept the self signed certificate. That should work.